# Check if comparator accepts object

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

In the [SortedMap doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) we have the following sentence:

> All keys inserted into a sorted map must implement the Comparable interface (or be accepted by the specified comparator)

**How would one check if a key (of a generic type as well) is accepted by the specified comparator?**

Furthermore, if the key *is* accepted by the comparator, isn't it by definition comparable?

code:

```
Comparator<KeyType> c = null; // not nesc. specified in constructor. 
public int comparePlz(KeyType k1, KeyType k2) {

    if (c != null)
        return c.compare(k1, k2);

    // if c is null, doc stipulates KeyType implements Comparable. 
    // However as expected this gives compiler error. But typecasting would
    // be unsafe. 

    return k1.compareTo(k2);


}
```

Sure I could just add `KeyType extends Comparable<? super KeyType>` but was wondering if there was a way to do it without that.

I also cannot add any parameters to the constructor.

Comment: `Comparable` is an interface in the Java API.  The key must `implement` that interface.

Comment: "comparable" and "implements the Comparable interface" are not synonyms.  But you should show us what code generates that error, without which we can't do much for you.

Comment: Is there a way for an object to **not** implement the Comparable interface **and** be accepted by some comparator? If not, why does the doc have the phrase "or be accepted by the specified comparator" ?

Comment: Yes, there is; it's pretty common.  You haven't shown us the declaration of `c` yet, however.

Comment: Good point - I had `Comparator<?> c` which I realized should be `Comparator<KeyType> c`, which fixed the compiler problem. I will update question.

Comment: 'I was wondering if there was a way to do it without that' why? when it's the answer to your question?

Comment: No, just trying to understand all the cases I have to cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ripping the implementation for this method straight from the
[TreeMap implementation](http://%09//%20http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.compare%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29).